# The code in the for loop is not executing

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, implementation

I created a while loop calculate the area and compare the price of that area with the given  price and if the given price is lower then our result is the calculated area. I need to print all the result in the end when the while loop break. Therefore I am storing the result in an array to print it when the while loop breaks but the for at the end is not executing.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = sc.nextInt();
    String[] result = new String[t];

    while (t != 0) {
        int j = 0;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        int w[] = new int[n];
        int h[] = new int[n];
        int p[] = new int[n];
        int area[] = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            w[i] = sc.nextInt();
            h[i] = sc.nextInt();
            p[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            area[i] = w[i] * h[i];
            System.out.println("Area: " + area[i]);
        }

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (b >= p[i]) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("count: " + count);

        if (count == 0) {
            result[j] = "no tablet";
        } else {
            int check[] = new int[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (b >= p[i]) {
                    check[i] = area[i];
                }
            }
            Arrays.sort(check);
            result[j] = "" + check[count - 1];
        }
        j++;
        t--;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + result[i]);
    }
```

Comment: which for loop? might be that the value is 0 from the start

Comment: How can you figure out what data is being asked for?  Put in some prompts.

Comment: What output are you getting? What is the value of `b` ? what are the values of `p` ?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<t;i++) {` isn't `t` already `0`

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<t;i++)` ==> `for (int i = 0; i < result.length - 1; i++)` might help a little...

Comment: Or even `for(String eachResult : result)`

Comment: This question is unclear.. what is the value of t before the while loop? Which loop does't run? While loop or for loop?

Comment: The only way you can escape from the `while` loop is if `t` has reached zero.  But if `t ==0`, then the fourth `for` loop will iterate exactly zero times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. I have removed the error and put some prompt for user to enter values. your last for loop was not running because in while loop your value of 't' becomes 0, and it the end you were using that t in the for loop condition, that's why it was not running. I have used another variable for that. so Your problem is resolved now. Here is the complete correct code.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        String[] result=new String[t];
        int x = t;

        while(t!=0) {
            int j=0;
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int b=sc.nextInt();
            int w[]=new int[n];
            int h[]=new int[n];
            int p[]=new int[n];
            int area[]=new int[n];

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Width for w["+i+"]: ");
                w[i]=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Height for h["+i+"]: ");
                h[i]=sc.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Enter Price for w["+i+"]: ");
                p[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                area[i]=w[i]*h[i];
                System.out.println("Area A["+i+"]: " +area[i]);
            }

            int count=0;

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                System.out.println("b = "+b+"  and p["+i+"] = "+p[i]);
                if(b>=p[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("count: "+count);

            if(count==0) {
                result[j]="no tablet";
            }else {

            int check[]=new int[count];

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                if(b>=p[i]) {
                    check[i]=area[i];
                }
            }

            Arrays.sort(check);
                        result[j]=""+check[count-1];




        }

            j++;
            t--;
        }


        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            System.out.println("Result: "+result[i]);
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

you must check your list grater than notation

like that

```
 while(t>0)
```

and area you must declaration  outside  while loop

i think like that

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        String[] result=new String[t];
        List area=new List<int>();

        while(t>0) {
            int j=0;
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int b=sc.nextInt();
            int w[]=new int[n];
            int h[]=new int[n];
            int p[]=new int[n];


            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                w[i]=sc.nextInt();
                h[i]=sc.nextInt();
                p[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                area.Add(w[i]*h[i]);
                System.out.println("Area: "+area[i]);
            }

            int count=0;

            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
                if(b>=p[i]) {
                    count++;

                }
            }

            System.out.println("count: "+count);

            if(count==0) {
                result[j]="no tablet";
            }else {

            int check[]=new int[count];

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
                if(b>=p[i]) {
                    check[i]=area[i];
                }
            }

            Arrays.sort(check);
                        result[j]=""+check[count-1];




        }

            j++;
            t--;
        }


        for(int i=0;i<t;i++) {
            System.out.println("Result: "+result[i]);
            }


    }
}
```

Comment: I believe that the two suggestions you've made won't solve OP's problem.  But if you think there's merit in them, maybe you could explain why.  Also, your code doesn't compile, which makes it difficult to gauge its usefulness as an answer.